# Source directories in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, openframeworks

I am using OF in my project and I want to use some add-ons but I have to add .cpp files to my project in order to compile them. I don't like it. Is there any option so I could specify a folder to scan for source files and compile every .cpp file it finds?

I thought it might be Source Directories in VC++ Directories section but it didn't work. Then I don't really get what it does.

Comment: What is "OF" that you are using in your project?  I hate abbreviations, when they can be spelled out.

Comment: OF maybe means Open Frameworks?

Comment: @morgancodes Yeah, I believe it was Open Frameworks I was working at that moment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to compile sources using Visual Studio, you will have to add them to your project.
There is nothing wrong about adding external sources to your project in a nice filter.

You can also create a makefile to be used by Visual Studio which will list sources you need.

Comment: I'll do as you said - make a filter for such .cpp files

Comment: @Valdo : Filters let you organize sources as you wish.
For your specific use, it will be good to have a filter "External" where you put all external sources you want to compile.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of an option that does what you ask for in VS. The Source directories configuration is used for locating source files that go along with libraries that you are using in your project. This way you can use the library in its binary format without the need to recompile it every time you rebuild your project, but you can also step into its code while debugging.

Comment: aaa... I see now... That makes sense.